# How to get pop up box after comment submitted in custom comment box?

Tags: wordpress, forms, dialog, popup, alert

I made custom file to add comment on posts, this file only contains a comment box. Now I want to show pop up dialogue box when user post a comment, this is my form

```
<form action="https://m.punjabidharti.com/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="author" id="author" class="textarea" value="" size="22" tabindex="1" />
        <label for="author">
            Name </label>
        (required)
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" size="22" tabindex="2" class="textarea" />
        <label for="email">
            E-mail </label>
        (required)
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="comment"><strong>Your Comment</strong></label>
        <br />
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="50" rows="10" tabindex="4" class="textarea"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
        <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" tabindex="5" value="submit" class="Cbutton" />

        <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo   $_GET["img"]; ?>" />

    </p>
    <p style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" id="akismet_comment_nonce" name="akismet_comment_nonce" value="9dc14cd05a" /></p>
    <p style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" id="ak_js" name="ak_js" value="165" /></p>
    <p>Comment moderation is enabled. Your comment may take some time to appear.</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with JavaScript?

Comment: yes i have tried many but not works @Tokant

Comment: FYI: There is just one language called JavaScript. Do you want to show the popup when the user submits the form or after the comment has been posted and saved in the database?

Comment: i want to show after the comment has been posted and saved in the database @Tokant

Comment: Then you could use an JavaScript to capture the form submission and make an AJAX call to a function. If the callback is successful, you show the popup (again with JavaScript). You could also use PHP to check for $POST to your page (https://m.punjabidharti.com/wp-comments-post.php) and if the comment was saved, show the HTML for the popup.

Comment: i don't know how to do that , can you please send me code ? @Tokant

Comment: I don't think anybody would just send you the code as it is quite complex because it depends on exactly your WordPress logic and which route you select. But I can point you in the right direction for my first suggestion. Search Google for "wordpress javascript AJAX calls", then do a couple of tutorials, and finally come back to this thread when you have understood it. Shouldn't take you more than an hour or two.